# checkstyle plugin throwing major.minor 52 error on maven package, development env problem

Tags: java, maven, build, development-environment

I believe this is an issue with my development environment since I was able to build this jar before I needed switch to a new laptop.

I need to build this jar with java version 1.7 due to production environment requirements.
In the pom.xml I have the properties

```
  <properties>
    <checkstyle.version>8.10.1</checkstyle.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

bash-3.2$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
bash-3.2$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.3_1/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

When I run:

```
mvn package -DbuildNum=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

It fails with the output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (compile) on project syn-dap-hadoop: Execution compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/api/CheckstyleException : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Changing my JAVA_HOME to java 1.8 allows it to build properly, but I need it to be built in 1.7 for the environment it runs in.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is no problem to build with JDK 1.8 for Java 1.7. The resulting artifacts will run on a Java 1.7 environment just fine.

If you don't want this, you need to downgrade your checkstyle plugin to a version that still support Java 1.7.

Comment: If I change my JAVA_HOME to 1.8 and build the jar.  When the jar runs in the production environment it throws a major.minor 52 error

Comment: Did you leave the `maven.compiler.source` at 1.7?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the checkstyle plugin?

Comment: I haven't since other members of my team have been able to build this jar with this version of checkstyle.

I asked a co-worker who can build this to do a mvn -version and they are using java 1.8 so I think I should close this question and make a new one for why mvn isn't using the pom.xml's maven.compiler.source